# In React Redux, how to reuse a hook that performs a fetch without needlessly performing that fetch more than once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a hook that I use in my components to access an external resource that is fetched through Ajax and saved in the Redux store. What I want is for this hook to handle fetching the resource if it's not already in the store, but simply returning the resource data if it is. However, I cannot get this to work, as the fetch is performed for every time I call the hook in different components.

This is how my Redux slice looks:

```
export const fetchResource = createAsyncThunk(
  'slice/resource',
  async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        'api.com/resource',
      );
      return data;
  },
);


const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'slice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchResource.pending, (state) => {
        state.resource.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(fetchResource.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.resource.status = 'success';
        state.resource.data = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchResource.rejected, (state) => {
        state.resource.status = 'error';
      });
  },
});
```

Then this is my hook:

```
export function useResource(initialFetch = false) {
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const status = useSelector(state => state.resource.status);
  const resource = useSelector(state => state.resource.resource);
  const refreshResource = useCallback(() => {
     dispatch(fetchResource());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
     if (initialFetch && status === 'idle') refreshResource();
  }, [initialFetch, status, refreshResource]);

  return {
    status,
    resource,
    refreshResource,
  }
}
```

This hook is meant so that if, in any component, I call `useResource(true)`, the hook will automatically fetch the resource and return it if it's missing in the store, or simply return it if it's found. As a side note, I'm wrapping the dispatch in the `refreshResource` so that I can return this function in the hook so that components will later be able to try to reload this resource if needed.

However, let's say I have the components `Child1` and `Child2`  that each include a call to `useResource(true)` , and then I have a `Parent` component that uses both `Child1` and `Child2` , the observed result is that the resource is fetched twice. I assumed this wouldn't happen as I added some logic for the resource to only be fetched if the fetching status is `idle` , and all components should be looking at and modifying the same status, right?

Why isn't this working and is there any way to fix it?

Also, this is not caused by StrictMode, as if I change any of the two calls to `useResource(true)` to be `useResource(false)`, I do get only one fetch.

A workaround I'm using right now is to call `useResource(false)` in the child components and `useResource(true)` in the `Parent` component, but this is not ideal as I want the child components to be independent of the parent, and to be able to reuse them in other components without having to worry about whether the resource has been fetched or not.

Comment: Your code has an error: you can't await in a non-async function.

Comment: @JaredSmith You're right. I've converted the function into an async one.

Comment: This functionality is a great candidate for using [Redux-Toolkit Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview). It is trivial to configure fetches only what it needs, when it needs it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should look into [Redux Toolkit Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview).

RTK Query is a powerful data fetching and caching tool. It is designed to simplify common cases for loading data in a web application, eliminating the need to hand-write data fetching & caching logic yourself. The data fetching and caching logic is built on top of Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` and `createAsyncThunk` APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually sure why your code would not work, but the hook looks a bit convoluted. I've written similar code before so I think something like this should do the trick:

```
export function useResource() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data, status } = useSelector(state => state.resource);

  const refreshResource = useCallback(() => {
    if (!data && status !== 'loading') {
      dispatch(fetchResource());
    }
  }, [data, status]);

  useEffect(() => {
    refreshResource();
  }, []);

  return {
    status,
    data,
    refreshResource,
  }
}
```

The effect does the initial fetch in case the store is empty. You don't need to add `dispatch` to a dependency array btw, it's a stable reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work. It seems that inside of the `fetchResource` function, as soon as it's called, the fetch status of the resource has already been set to "loading" by the `fetchResource.pending` case that's defined in the slice, therefore, the resource would never get fetched with this code. As you say, it seems cleaner to check before calling `refreshResource`, but isn't that what I'm doing in my original code?

Comment: @SirRastusBear Oops, forgot about the automatic pending. I've edited the answer. Try this.